# Tables being queried with SQL and Sqlalchemy have same column names

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I am querying a variety of different tables in a mysql database with sqlalchemy, and SQL query code.

My issue right now is renaming some of the columns being joined. The queries are all coming into one dataframe.

```
SELECT *
FROM original

LEFT JOIN table1 
    on original.id = table1.t1key

LEFT JOIN table2 
    on original.id = table2.t2key

LEFT JOIN table3
    on original.id = table3.t3key;
```

All I actually want to get from those tables is a single column added to my query. Each table has a column with the same name. My approach to using an alias has been as below,

```
table1.columnchange AS 'table1columnchange'
table2.columnchange AS 'table2columnchange'
table3.columnchange AS 'table3columnchange'
```

But the variety of ways I've tried to implement this ends up with annoying errors.

I am querying around 20 different tables as well, so using `SELECT *` at the beginning while inefficient is ideal for the sake of ease.

The output I'm looking for is a dataframe that has each of the columns I need in it (which I am trying to then filter and build modeling with python for). I am fine with managing the query through sqlalchemy into pandas, the alias is what is giving me grief right now.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nested queries:

```
SELECT
 original.column1 as somename,
 table1.column1 as somename1,
 table2.column1 as somename2
FROM
 (SELECT
    column1
 FROM
    original
 ) original
 LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        column1
    FROM
        table1
 ) table1 ON original.id = table1.t1key
 LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        column1
    FROM
        table2
 ) table2 ON original.id = table2.t2key
```

Comment: Actually, the top part I used with the select functions, as I can make the aias while also using * to select all. The left join with the bracated data was what was breaking it I believe.